# How to make a directory when a user registers (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a file storing site. My users are able to log in and register. Now what I am trying to do is allow users to create a directory in a not publicly accessible part of the folder based on the email.
Say the email : jdoe@yahoo.com then a directory by that name should be created.

Say I am in htdocs/testsite/. The dir should be made like htdocs/files/jdoe@yahoo.com

Also, only the user jdoe should be able to read and write files and directories to it.
here is my register code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration Page</title></head>
<body>
    <?php
    require('dbcon.php');
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $fname = stripslashes($fname);
        $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);

        $lname = stripslashes($lname);
        $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($lname);

        $email = stripslashes($email);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);

        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

        $query = "INSERT into `dropdriveusers` (fname,lname,email,password) VALUES ('$fname','$lname', '$email','" . md5($password) . "')";
        $endresult = mysql_query($query);
        mkdir($_SESSION["email"]);
        if ($endresult) {
            echo "<h3>Account Registeration has been completed</h3><br/>Please click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a>";
        }
    } else {
        ?>

        <h1>Registration</h1>
        <form name="rform" action="" method="post" onsubmit="Validate()">
            <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required />
            <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Lirst Name" required /><br>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email-ID" required /><br>
            <input type="email" name="vmail" placeholder="Confirm your Email-ID" required /><br>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a password" required /><br>
            <input type="password" name="passcheck" placeholder="Confirm your password" required /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
        </form>
    <?php } ?>
</body>
```

>

Comment: do you want to create folder with registered user name?

Comment: Yes exactly that. It should be in a directory above the current folder. Say I am in htdocs/testsite/. The dir should be made like htdocs/files/jdoe@yahoo.com

Comment: mkdir($path . $username) see [mkdir](http://php.net/mkdir) don't forget to set the permissions for the folder (read write etc.)

Comment: Just don't, that doesn't sound like a good idea. You probably merely want your *URLs* to **look like** there's a "folder" for that user. You achieve this with URL rewrite rules. You should generally avoid dynamically generating new files and folders on disk; the only exception really is for the purpose of *data storage*.

Comment: If you **don't** want those files accessible over http, and assuming `htdocs` is your docroot - you would be better off having that `files` directory outside the docroot altogether: e.g. instead of `path-to-your-server/htdocs/files` go up a level to just `path-to-your-server/files/` ... there are some potential serious security gotchas with user files though... and the fact that you're using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension makes me think you might not be up to snuff (hell, I'm not sure I am - but I'm aware of the risks).

Comment: I am an absolute novice at this.

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
<?php
$dirname = "htdocs/files/".$email;
mkdir($dirname);
?>
```

More infor about [mkdir](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_mkdir.asp)

**syntax** for *mkdir*: `mkdir(path,mode,recursive,context)`

```
path --> Required. Specifies the name of the directory to create
mode --> Optional. Specifies permissions. By default, the mode is 0777 (widest possible access).

The mode parameter consists of four numbers:

The first number is always zero
The second number specifies permissions for the owner
The third number specifies permissions for the owner's user group
The fourth number specifies permissions for everybody else

Possible values (to set multiple permissions, add up the following numbers):

1 = execute permissions
2 = write permissions
4 = read permissions

recursive --> Optional. Specifies if the recursive mode is set (added in PHP 5)
context   --> Optional. Specifies the context of the file handle. Context is a set of options that can modify the behavior of a stream (added in PHP 5)
```

Comment: As mkdir defaults to 0777, always try to change the mode as per requirement.

Comment: @booota i have just copied from link i have provided :)

Comment: :) that was just a suggestion as mostly we don't want our directories to be globally readable/writable/executable.